# Big O notation of nested sequential loops

Tags: big-o

I have been searching through the forums on big O notation and learned quite a bit.  My problem is pretty specific and I think a unique case will better help me understand big O,  I am ignoring constants.

To my understanding if a loop goes through all elements than it's O(n).

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   

}
```

If a loop goes through all of n, inside another loop that goes through all of n, it's multiplied      n * n = n^2

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {

    }
}
```

Lastly if a loop is followed by another loop that goes through all elements it is n + n = 2n

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{

}
for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{

}
```

My question directly proceeds these lines of code

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{             
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)    
    {

    }
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {

    }
    for(int l = 0; l < n; l++)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
        {

        }
    }
```

}

So based on the rules above I am calculating big O to be n * (n + n + n * n), which is n^3 + 2n^2.  So would that make my big O(n^3) or would my big O be O(n^3 +2n^2).  Am I going about this all wrong?  Or am I somewhere close in the ballpark?  Mainly I'm trying to figure out if these loops would be less than O(n^4).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big-O notation is used to characterize the asymptotic behavior of an algorithm depending on some value n that indicates the data volume, but independent of any constant, e.g. processor speed.
In your example, n^3 grown faster than 2n^2, i.e., for large n, 2n^2 can be neglected compared to n^3. The asymptotic behavior of your nested loops thus have order O(n^3).